# Unable to switch to a new window when using IE11

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the following code (which works for FireFox, obviously the before section is different) but doesn't work in IE11:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
baseUrl = "not important";
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer().setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
cap.setCapability("IE.binary", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe");
cap.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
cap.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
cap.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", true);
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\pabraham\\Documents\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1\\IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver.extractpath","C:\\Users\\pabraham\\Documents\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1\\");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.logfile","C:\\Users\\pabraham\\Documents\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1\\IEDriverServer.log");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",file.getAbsolutePath());

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Main Test:

```
@Test
public void testExportedScript() throws Exception {
driver.get(baseUrl + "not important");

driver.findElement(By.id("overridelink")).click();
//TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2); //This causes the password to fail???
String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys("123");
driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys("123");
driver.findElement(By.id("j_id26")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("workbenchPanel:j_id60:3:applications:1:j_id67")).findElement(By.linkText("UW")).click();
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    if (!handle.equals(currentHandle))
    {
        System.out.println("Try to select new window");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    }
}

String srnChk;
srnChk = driver.findElement(By.id("workbenchPanel:j_id60:3:applications:1:j_id67")).findElement(By.linkText("UW")).getText();
System.out.println("Check if its on the original screen: "+srnChk);
System.out.println("Try to click the override link");
driver.findElement(By.id("overridelink")).click();

TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
```

I added the screen check variable at the end to show what's going on.

The error that I get is: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == overridelink

The console shows that the code is not hitting the "Try to select new window" section of the code:

Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.53.1.0
Listening on port 15536
Library extracted to C:\Users\pabraham\Documents\Selenium\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1
Only local connections are allowed
Check if its on the original screen: UW
Try to click the override link

The html (it's the standard web security certificate screen):

```
<td id="continueToSiteAlign" align="left" valign="middle" aria-labelledby="continueToSite">
    <h4 id="continueToSite">
        <img src="red_shield.png" ID="ImgOverride" border="0" alt="Not recommended icon" class="actionIcon"><A href='' ID="overridelink" NAME="overridelink" >Continue to this website (not recommended).</A>
    </h4>
    </td>
```

Just out of curiosity, when I add a wait before entering the user name and password, the system says that the user id and password is incorrect. When I take the wait out it signs in without a problem.

Comment: Oddly, if I take the 5 second wait out (before the for statement), the console shows that the 'Try to select new window' section of the code is hit, however I get the following error: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: No window found

Comment: Just to clarify: I believe that the problem I’ve got is that I’m unable to select the new window that is loaded because I get the error:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: No window found

I’ve added various system outputs to see what’s going on and the code falls over when it hits:
driver.switchTo().window(handle);

Comment: Just to clarify: I get the certificate error when I first load IE and I’m able to click the ‘Continue to this website (not recommended)’ button with:
driver.findElement(By.id(“overridelink”)).click();

This allows access to the first page, I then input user id and password, I click on ‘UW’ which loads a new window (with the security certificate), I then get the error when trying to switch to the new window: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: No window found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve managed to get this working now. I just had to tick the ‘Enable Protected Mode’ for Internet, Local internet and Trusted sites (Internet options > Security tab).

It also looks like ‘driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).clear();’ was causing the password to fail. I’ve taken that out and I haven’t had a problem since. I'm assuming that it was caused by a timing issue since this should've been run before the password was entered.